# Super_L not working as Mod4 with Das Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm running Oneiric with Awesome WM. The keyboard seems to get detected with dmesg:

```
[   10.856491] input: daskeyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1.2/1-2.1.2:1.0/input/input3
[   10.856578] generic-usb 0003:04D9:2013.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [daskeyboard] on usb-0000:00:12.2-2.1.2/input0
[   10.879781] input: daskeyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-2/1-2.1/1-2.1.2/1-2.1.2:1.1/input/input4
[   10.879867] generic-usb 0003:04D9:2013.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [daskeyboard] on usb-0000:00:12.2-2.1.2/input1
```

But when I run xev, it doesn't detect any events when I press and release the key.

Super_R works fine.

Here's the output of xmodmap:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a version of Das Keyboard where "Super_L" is in fact a key to transform FN keys to volume and other media stuff.

Comment: Yep that was it :)

Comment: Is there a way to force the Super_L key to behave like a normal winkey?